# How can I map the root path of my web application using struts2?

Tags: java, struts2, struts-config

When I run my strust2 web application, I want to execute an action for the root path `[/]`. 
It would be something like an action with no name or just `"/"`, something like:

```
<action name="/" class="ControllerName" method="execute">
        <result name="success">ShowTheFirstPageAfterTheAction.jsp</result>
 </action>
```

Comment: What you are asking is unclear and the question has not the proper statement/format, please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and learn how to ask a good question on StackOverflow

Comment: You're referring to the "welcome page"; a quick web or SO search will get you what you want.

Comment: @SsouLlesS You are right. I should have read the the "how-to-ask" before posting this question. Im so sorry about it. I still really dont know how to execute an action before the welcome page gets displayed, but as soon as I learn how Ill post it here.

Answer (score 0):

```
...
<struts>
...
    <package name="user" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
       <action name="" class="ControllerName" method="execute">
           <result name="success">ShowTheFirstPageAfterTheAction.jsp</result>
       </action>
       // Other actions depending on how you've designed your application
    <package
    // Other packages (also) depending on how you've designed your application
</struts>
```